# Block countries based on IP in firewall

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall

I would like to restrict visibility of my server from outside my country. I am connecting to my personal server always from one or two countries. Is there a way to block all the IPs coming from all the other countries?

I am running `Debian` with `iptables`.

I have found the following database of IPs associated to countries, however it's not very accurate. Any other idea?

```
ftp://ftp.arin.net/pub/stats/arin/delegated-arin-extended-latest (North America)
ftp://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/stats/delegated-ripencc-latest  (Europe)
ftp://ftp.afrinic.net/pub/stats/afrinic/delegated-afrinic-latest (Africa)
ftp://ftp.apnic.net/pub/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-latest (Asia + Pacific)
ftp://ftp.lacnic.net/pub/stats/lacnic/delegated-lacnic-latest (South America)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use xtable addons geoip match feature. On debian install the xtable-addons-common package and then use use the geoip target e.g. to allow ssh from Netherlands NL:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m geoip --src-cc NL -j ACCEPT
```

Make sure xt_geoip module is loaded and geoip database is downloaded. You can read xtable documentation for more information on this at http://xtables-addons.sourceforge.net/geoip.php

Comment: Cool. What if my ip ends up in the wrong country in the database and I cannot access the server anymore? Is there  way to make a rule in iptables that will "prevail" over the other rules?

Comment: Just add an accept rule for your IP before the drop/reject geoio rules and everything should be fine